# WebView not responding when called from a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, methods

I have an app with tabbar and webview. I'm trying to make the app come back to default url each time user taps the bar. Right now I'm intercepting taps and launching a method, however it's not affecting my webview (it's not loading the page). The method works properly when called from the class, but not when it's called from my app delegate, where I'm intercepting taps.

I suspect it's something with the way I create the SecondViewController object that it's not pointing to the webview, but I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code:

Second view header (where the WebView is located)

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIWebView *secondView;
}
- (void) goToPage;
```

Second view implementation

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@implementation SecondViewController
- (void)awakeFromNib 
{
    [self goToPage];
}

- (void) goToPage
{
    NSLog(@"go to page");
    NSString *newURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://pageurl"];
    [secondView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newURL]]];
}
```

My app delegate, where I call the SecondViewController class method:

```
#import "RedDragonAppDelegate.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation RedDragonAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize rootController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window addSubview:rootController.view];
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSLog(@"didSelectViewController %d", rootController.selectedIndex);

    SecondViewController * sv = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

    if (rootController.selectedIndex == 0){
        //NSLog(@"if in didSelectViewController 0");
    } else if (rootController.selectedIndex == 1) {
        //NSLog(@"if in didSelectViewController 1");
        [sv goToPage];
    }
}
```

Thanks fot your help!

Comment: I'm assuming that you are in fact seeing `go to page` in your log, so you know `goToPage` is being called.  Are the original URL and the new URL the same?  Does the call from `goToPage` work if you replace `newURL` (in `NSURL URLWithString:`) with, e.g., `@"http://www.google.com/"`?

Comment: haha I wouldn't be posting it if I didn't check the obvious :)
Indeed, I know that the function is being executed and I'm certain that new URL is not being loaded.

I did figure out half of the problem though. When I changed [ptr goToPage]; to [self goToPage]; it started working BUT... I still have to call it from another class. When I create the object like this: SecondViewController *ptr = [[SecondViewController alloc] init]; the function gets executed, however the webview is not activated. :(

Any idea why?

Comment: How is `secondView` being set?  Maybe there's a retain/release/autorelease issue?

Comment: I honestly don't know what that means :) I set it like this: @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController { IBOutlet UIWebView *secondView; }

Comment: So `secondView` is an `IBOutlet` that you're connecting in Interface Builder (connecting from the `IBOutlet` of an instance of `SecondViewController` to the actual `UIWebView`).  In a previous comment, you said `[self goToPage]` works, but when you're calling it from somewhere else outside `SecondViewController`, it doesn't.  Could you edit your question to include the code that doesn't work that calls `goToPage`?

Comment: thanks for your help Isaac :) it's exactly like you said, I connected secondView webview with SecondViewController. When I launch it with self it works. I've included the code in my app delegate which launches goToPage. Is it because SecondController is declared as UIViewController and not pointing directly to webview? You can tell I'm Obj-C noob. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you've got an instance of `SecondViewController` with `secondView` connected to an instance of `UIWebView` in Interface Builder.  What you want to do is call `goToPage` on that instance of `SecondViewController` from `RedDragonAppDelegate`.  (In particular, note that I'm talking about *instances* of these--I believe this is the underlying issue.)

In `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`, when you do `SecondViewController * sv = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];`, you are creating a new instance of `SecondViewController` and you can call its `goToPage` method, but `sv` is not the same instance of `SecondViewController` that appears in Interface Builder and has `secondView` connected to the `UIWebView` (that is, when you create a new *instance* of `SecondViewController`, the ivar `secondView` is unset and seems to be `nil`, but I don't know that it's guaranteed to be `nil`).

What you probably(*) want to do is add `IBOutlet SecondViewController *sv;` to the `@interface` of `RedDragonAppDelegate`, make sure that you have an instance of `RedDragonAppDelegate` in Interface Builder, connect the new IBOutlet `sv` of `RedDragonAppDelegate` to the instance of `SecondViewController` in Interface Builder, and delete the line in `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` that defines and initializes `sv`.

(*) I'm not 100% certain on this because I don't do iPhone stuff and I don't know how your various views/objects/etc. are arranged in XIB/NIB files, but if everything's in one XIB/NIB file, I'm pretty sure it'll work.

Comment: Isaac, you're a genius! You found the problem and explained the solution in a way I could understand (with my limited knowledge)! Keep it up man! :)